# Index rebuild on CM server only updates some CD servers in Sitecore

Tags: solr, events

I have a Sitecore architecture with 1 CM server and 4 CD servers split into an A and B environment (2 servers each). The A and B environments each have their own separate databases (uatadb and uatbdb).

There are also separate Solr environments for A and B, with 3 Solr servers for A (solr uat a) and 3 for B (solr uat b).

When I do an index rebuild from the indexing manager on the CM server for the sitecore_web_index, it only updates the Solr servers for environment A (solr uat a). The Solr servers for environment B (solr uat b) do not get updated.

The CM and CD A servers share the same core database.

I checked the event queue tables in the core databases for both CD A and CD B. The event queue is getting updated in CD A but not in CD B.

I tried setting up merge replication between the core databases of CD A and CD B, but this did not resolve the issue.

How can I get the index rebuild on the CM server to update the Solr indexes on both the A and B CD environments? What do I need to configure or set up differently so that the event queue tables are populated properly in both core databases?

Comment: What are the databases linked from CM server? What are configurations of your indexes on all CM and CD servers? And what are index strategies on all the servers? Include config snippets in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with the `SOLR cloud` and the `Index Replication/Master-Slave` approach can solve your issue.

Index Replication distributes complete copies of a master index to one or more slave servers. The master server continues to manage updates to the index. All querying is handled by the slaves. This division of labor enables Solr to scale to provide adequate responsiveness to queries against large search volumes.

The figure below shows a Solr configuration using index replication. The master server’s index is replicated on the slaves.

[image]

Sharing SOLR articles here that describe it in detail:

1. [Index Replication](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/index-replication.html)
2. [Using ZooKeeper to Manage Configuration Files](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/using-zookeeper-to-manage-configuration-files.html)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello @Himmat , Apologies forgot to mention, we are already using solr cloud setup using Zookeeper configuration.